Do you say "you're very reasonative" the same way we say "you're very talkative"?
A talkative person is one who talks a lot.
So, I deduce a reasonative person is one who often gives a lot of reasons for his/her behaviors.
There is no "reasonative" entry in dictionary, but I do see it in Google books.
Say, my daughter hates learning math. So, when I ask her to do it, sometimes she invents or makes up many reasons (for example, I'm so tired, I'm busy drawing now, etc) to avoid it.
I think, in that situation, I'll say "don't give an excuse" or "don't make excuses for yourself / for your laziness / for not learning math"
But, in that situation, Vietnamese often says "you have so many reasons" (translated literally). I am not sure if we can say "you're very reasonative" in this case?

The Google Books results are actually incorrect scans of the word "reasonable".

"reasonative" is not an English word - so no, you can't use it.

You'd think AI could recognize a column break. Google's OCR algorithms are crude. They can't even get a gestalt of the page layout.

There's no such word.  All these examples you refer to seem to be errors/typos or the result of bad scans.

BTW, there is an idiomatic expression in English, "to be full of excuses".  This describes someone who makes a lot of excuses, or who has an excuse for everything.  So, you can say things such as "You are full of excuses". Use that instead!

In my mind, creating reasonative by the parallel talkative -> reasonative would suggests a person who thinks a lot

No, that's not a recognized English word. If you check the results in Google Books, you'll see that it tends to be an ocr failure of the word "reasonable", or used in philosophy. I'm not seeing the page reference for the philosophical usage, but based on the books I expect it has more to do with reason as in rational rather than reason as in excuse.

As others have noted, "reasonative" is not a recognized English word. You can try using it, of course. There are no Language Police who will arrest you for making up an unauthorized word. But no one will know what you mean. You'd have to explain it every time you used it. At which point, you might as well just use some recognized words and avoid the problem. Like say, "You have a lot of excuses" instead of "You're very reasonative. By 'reasonative' I mean that you have a lot of excuses."
You could, of course, start using it and hope it catches on. But frankly, it is very difficult to invent a new word and get millions of people to accept it and use it. Not impossible, people have done it. But it's hard. Usually you have to be someone with a platform, like a popular TV host or some such.

It's a creative analogy - "reasonative" is not a word that I have heard before, but you're welcome to start using it and see if it catches on!
